# How to read & understand C & C++ Standards and the language grammar used therein?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, standards, grammar

I often find C and C++ Standards difficult to read and understand, even the simple English sentences and their wordings give terrible experience. On the top of it, the language grammar is totally hell. I'm sure many share the same feeling, at least my friends do.

I would like to understand it by some examples. Lets begin with this (which tries to explain why `the conditional expression in C++` is **different** from `the conditional expression in C` : (quoted from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Notes))

> *The binding of operators in C and C++
>   is specified (in the corresponding
>   Standards) by a factored language
>   grammar, rather than a precedence
>   table.* This creates some subtle
>   conflicts. For example, in C, the
>   syntax for a conditional expression
>   is:
>
> **logical-OR-expression ? expression :
>   conditional-expression**
>
> while in C++ it is:
>
> **logical-OR-expression ? expression :
>   assignment-expression**
>
> Hence, the expression:
>
> e = a < d ? a++ : a = d
>
> is parsed differently in the two
>   languages. In C, this expression is a
>   syntax error, but many compilers parse
>   it as:
>
> e = ((a < d ? a++ : a) = d)
>
> which is a semantic error, since the
>   result of the conditional-expression
>   (which might be a++) is not an lvalue.
>   In C++, it is parsed as:
>
> e = (a < d ? a++ : (a = d))
>
> which is a valid expression.

Please someone explain the **bold text** in the above quotation! Please explain the grammar with few more examples (especially those where C and C++ differ).

EDIT : I just want to know **how** to read and understand them. I mean, if I were to explain that in spoken English, then how would I do that?

Comment: The ISO standards use EBNF for their grammar descriptions. Do you understand how to read this? If so the grammar rules should be pretty clear. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form

Comment: Are you sure you mean "terrific experience" (wonderful) and not "terrifying experience" (horrible)? :)

Comment: @FredOverflow... http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/terrific

Comment: There are good reasons that such standards are not written in 'plain English'; not the least of these is that 'plain English' is generally ambiguous and the standards are intended to be unambiguous. These standards are not intended to provide a source of learning material for beginners, but a reference for compiler-writers (and allied trades).

Comment: @Nawaz: that third meaning is archaic -- no one uses it that way anymore.  "Terrifying" (or perhaps "terrible") are the words you want.

Comment: @wnoise.. hehe... now changed that to 'terrible'.. thanks :-)

Comment: upvoted for the sincere learning attempt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a description of the [C++ grammar for expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903591(VS.71).aspx), which defines assignment-expression as

```
assignment-expression:
    conditional-expression 
    unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
```

In plain English, an assignment-expression can be either a conditional-expression OR a unary-expression, followed by an assignment-operator, followed by an assignment-expression. So, your next question is 'what's a conditional expression' and you consult that part of the grammar, and keep going until you reach the bottom!

So in C++ you can see the operator you referred to can take a 'conditional-expression' as in C, but also an assignment

So with your 'C' hat on, you look at the final `a = d` part of the operator as an assignment, which the C syntax shouldn't allow. Instead, it would seem some compilers parse the final part of the operator simple as `a` to to give

```
 e = (a < d ? a++ : a) = d
```

But in C++, it's valid to find an assignment there, so the `a = d` is accepted in its entirety as the final expression, so you get

```
 e = (a < d ? a++ : (a = d))
```

Comment: . such expressions are throughout in the Standards...I just want to know how to read and understand them. I mean, if I were to explain that in spoken English, then how would I do that?

Comment: .. thanks for the edit... now I can understand something. :-)

Comment: Your reference for the _assignment-expression_ in C++ is incorrect. In C++ an _assignment-expression_ can be " _logical-or-expression_ _assignment-operator_ _assignment-expression_ ", the first part is only just " _unary-expression_ " in C.

Comment: It's a recursive descent parser tree syntax. H treated if and you should be good

Answer (score 6):

You have to refer to what an *assignment-expression* is. It is defined in the C++03 standard in 5.17/1 [expr.ass] :

```
assignment-expression:
        conditional-expression
        logical-or-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
        throw-expression

assignment-operator: one of
        = *= /= %= += -= >>= <<= &= ˆ= |=
```

What it says is that an *assignment-expression* can be *either* :

- A *conditional-expression*
- A *logical-or-expression* followed by an *assignment-operator* followed by an *assignment-expression*
- A *throw-expression*.

I'm not quoting the grammar definition of everything because that would be pretty huge (most notably because *condition-expression* covers a lot of things).

So the first thing we see is that an assignment-expression *can* be a conditional-expression, so we have the C syntax covered. What the C++ standard adds is that the right side of the `:` can also be something containing an *assignment-operator* or a *throw*.

The provided example is good : `e = a < d ? a++ : a = d`.

Here, the right side of the `:` is a *logical-or-expression* (`a`, because *unary-expression* is included in *logical-or-expression*), followed by an *assignment-operator* (`=`), followed by an assignment-expression (`d`, because *unary-expression* is included in *assignment-expression*).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, things like:

```
assignment-expression:
    conditional-expression 
    unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
```

(as mentioned in some other answers here) are rules used for describing the "grammar" of valid C (or C++). These written-down rules adhere to a certain grammar, too — so I would suggest that you learn that grammar, so that you'll be able to read and understand the rules.

**For a start, you could study e.g. the [Backus-Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)**, if you don't already know it. (My link goes to the Wikipedia article on this topic.) While the C++ standard doesn't use Backus-Naur form (IIRC), it's similar enough to get you started.